# Why can I not return firebase.database().ref() directly?

Tags: typescript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

If I return firebase.database().ref() directly and then try to do database.push(), I get the error "database.push() is not a function".

However, if I return only firebase.database() and then do database().ref().push() then it does work.

1) I tried making the returning function asynchronous, didn't work.
2) I tried doing
const database = firebase.database();
return database.ref(); 
But that doesn't work either.

Firebase.ts

```
export class Firebase implements Service<Req, Sub> {
  private firebaseRef: App;

  constructor(dispatch: Dispatch<any>) {
    this.firebaseRef = !firebase.apps.length
                       ? firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASECONFIG, AppName)
                       : firebase.apps[0];
  }

// Here I return the reference to the database 
  public async database() {
    return await this.firebaseRef.database().ref(); 
  }
}
```

Database.ts

```
export const postData = <E>(
  data: string,
  Error: Error<E>,
): Req<any> => ({
    service: Firebase,
    request: {
      run: async (firebaseRef: Firebase) => {
        try {
          const database = await firebaseRef.database();

          // database.push() is not a function
          await database.push(data);
        } catch (e) {
          return new Error(ErrorInfo.make(e));
        }
      },
    },
});
```

Expected Results: Firebase Realtime Database reference is returned and the data is pushed.

Actual Results: 'database.push() is not a function' error.

Comment: There's no need to use async/await with `this.firebaseRef.database().ref()`.  It's not asynchronous, and it doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand. However, I tried making it into an asynchronous function because it just won't return the reference. Even if I make it into a synchronous function, it doesn't return the reference. It only returns the reference if I first return this.firebaseRef.database() and then call ref() on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't return the reference"?  What *does* it do if not that?  Use a debugger.

Comment: @DougStevenson The reference is logged as a 'Reference' object in the function. But when it is returned by the function after it is called, the same is logged as a 'Database' object. Literally the same variable.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what firebaseRef is. I doubt you are actually calling that database method you defined. Use a debugger to trace the calls.